# Divide object array elements into groups of n each javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an Object as below:

```
const boxOfFruits = {
  apples: [
    {
      name: "Kashmiri",
    },
    {
      name: "Washington",
    },
    {
      name: "Himalayan",
    },
    {
      name: "Fuji",
    }
  ],
  oranges: [
    {
      name: "Nagpur",
    },
    {
      name: "Clementine",
    },
  ],
mangoes: [
    {
      name: "Totapuri",
    },
    {
      name: "Alphonso",
    },
    {
      name: "Langda",
    },
  ],
}
```

I want to divide these fruits into boxes; maximum of n each, let's say where n is 3 and apples, oranges and mangoes are equally distributed.

So the output in this case would be:

```
box_1 = [{name: "Kashmiri"}, {name: "Nagpur"},{name: "Totapuri"}];
box_2 = [{name: "Washington"}, {name: "Clementine"},{name: "Alphonso"}];
box_3 = [{name: "Himalayan"},{name: "Langda"}, {name: "Fuji"}];
```

The type of fruits(apple,oranges,etc)/keys in object can increase/decrease and n is also variable. In case total fruits are less than n, then it would be just 1 box of fruits.

What I have tried so far:

Using Lodash, I am calculating the minimum and the maximum fruits in a single type:

```
const minFruitType = _.min(Object.values(basket).map((eachBasket: any) => eachBasket.length));
```

Total teams will the sum of the fruits / n

Will distribute the minimum fruits (l) in the first l boxes and fill the rest with the remaining fruits at every iteration while at the start of every iteration will calculate the minimum type of fruits again.

Comment: sounds good. What have you come up with so far?

Comment: I'll add what I have done so far in the question, my bad.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Object.values()`, `array#reduce` and `array#forEach` to transform your object.

```js
const boxOfFruits = { apples: [ { name: "Kashmiri", }, { name: "Washington", }, { name: "Himalayan", }, ], oranges: [ { name: "Nagpur", }, { name: "Clementine", }, ], mangoes: [ { name: "Totapuri", }, { name: "Alphonso", }, { name: "Langda", }, ], },
    result = Object.values(boxOfFruits).reduce((r, arr) => {
      arr.forEach((o,i) => {
        const key =  `box_${i+1}`;
        r[key] ??= r[key] || [];
        r[key].push(o)
      });
      return r;
    },{});
console.log(result);
```

Comment: If I add another fruit to apple, the above code does not work, it creates box 3 with two fruits and box 4 with 1. Whereas Box 3 should have 3 fruits which is the requirements per box

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way would be to use [lodash.js](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#zip)'s `zip()` function:

```
const boxes = _.zip( Object.values(boxOfFruits) );
```

Note that `_.zip()` will give you undefined values when the source arrays are different lengths, so you'll need/want to filter those out:

```
const boxes == _.zip( Object.values(boxOfFruits) )
               .map(
                 box => box.filter(
                   x => x !== undefined
                 )
               );
```

But that will not distribute the fruits evenly. For that, it shouldn't get much for difficult than this:

```
function distribute(boxOfFruits, n) {

  const boxes = [];
  const fruits = Object.keys(boxOfFruits);
  
  for ( const fruit of fruits ) {

    let i = 0;
    const items = boxOfFruits[fruit];

    for (const item of items) {
      boxes[i] = !boxes[i] ?? [];
      boxes[i] = boxes[i].push(item);
      ++i;
      i = i < n ? i : 0 ;
    }

  }

  return boxes;
}
```

Comment: same parts in your answer were not working for me, have updated and shared my own answer. Do check

Answer (score 0):

A modified version of @Nicholas Carey's answer worked for me:

```
function distribute(boxOfFruits, n) {
  let boxes = [];

  let totalFruits = Object.values(boxOfFruits)
    .reduce((content, current) => content + current.length, 0);
  let maxBoxes = Math.ceil(totalFruits / 4);

  Object.values(boxOfFruits).forEach((fruits) => {
    let i = 0;
    fruits.forEach((fruit) => {
      boxes[i] ??= boxes[i] || [];
      boxes[i].push(fruit);
      ++i;
      i = i < (n+1) ? i : 0;
    });
  });

  // Extra boxes created, redistribute them to
  // starting boxes
  let newBoxes = teams.slice(0, maxBoxes);
  let pendingBoxes = teams.slice(maxBoxes);
  let pendingFruits = pendingBoxes.flat();

  let distributedBoxes = newBoxes.map((eachBox) => {
    let required = n - eachBox.length;
    if (required > 0) {
      eachBox.push(...pendingFruits.splice(0, required));
    }
    return eachBox;
  });

  return distributedBoxes;
}
```

Code is pretty much the same as Nicholas's accept the below changes:

1. Directly fetched the values and iterated over those
2. empty array creation was failing, this way works
3. and checking on the max box size with n+1 instead of n